# Performance cost of GROUP_CONCAT without entries to aggregate?

Tags: mysql, group-by, group-concat

Does having group_concat in SQL have any performance cost when the data at the time does not have multiple entries per GROUP parameter?

```
select group_concat(user_names) 
  from stuff
 group 
    by stuff_name
```

where there is only 1 user_names per stuff_name

will the engine simplify this into a non-group query?

Comment: No. It won't. Next (padding)

Comment: Let's see `EXPLAIN` for the query with and without the grouping.